# phpspreadsheet setFormatCode not working

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

Sometimes I'm unable to format an Excel cell data as date using `$date` wiht format 'yyyy-mm-dd' (eg. 2017-07-12)

```
if ($date != '') {
     $t_date   = PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::stringToExcel($date);
     $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($column,$row, $t_date);
     $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column,$row)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_DDMMYYYY);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous code fails when a `$date` is not valid (eg. 0000-00-00), and keeps failing in all sequent applies.

My solution is

```
if ($date != '') {
     $t_date   = PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::stringToExcel($date);
     if ($t_date !== false) {
        $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($column,$row, $t_date);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column,$row)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_DDMMYYYY);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column,$row)->getFont()->setBold(true);
        $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($column,$row)->getFont()->setBold(false);
     }
  }
```

Settting and unsetting the bold stile kwwpd working the setFormatCode in moste fo the cases ... I do not know why.