# how to customize date format in phpspreadsheet?

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I wanted to customize date in phpspreadsheet.

```
Feb 10, 2019 11:34:04
```

That's the default format but I wanted to add `PM` or `AM` at the end.

Is there any way to customize date format in phpspreadsheet?
These two aren't working.

```
$sheet->getStyle($cell)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_TIME1);

$sheet->getStyle($cell)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('MMM dd,yyyy hh:mm:ss aa');
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47883697/phpspreadsheet-setformatcode-not-working Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
$birthday = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($birthday));
$sheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$numRow, $birthday);
```